# Insertion of records based on some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to insert few records from the temporary table using a SQL Server stored procedure. There is a percentage column in the temporary table and a PQ number column. In a table there may exists more than 1 row with the same PQ number. But for insertion to happen the sum of percentage for the same PQ number should be 100%. I couldn't write the where clause for this situation.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Upsert_DebitSheet]
    @filename VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

    RETRY: -- Label RETRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[DebitSheet]([Date], [RMMName], [Invoice],[PQNumber], [CAF],
                                       [Percentage], [Amount], [FileName])
            SELECT 
                *, @filename 
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                     [Date], [RMMName], [Invoice], [PQNumber], [CAF],
                     [Percentage], [Amount]
                 FROM 
                     [dbo].[TempDebitSheet]
                 WHERE) result

        SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

        TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[TempDebitSheet]

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205 -- Deadlock Error Number
        BEGIN
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.05' -- Wait for 5 ms
            GOTO RETRY -- Go to Label RETRY
        END
    END CATCH

    SET ROWCOUNT 0;
END
```

[Temporary Table](https://postimg.org/image/5ihqnv169/)

[MainTable(Expected Result)](https://postimg.org/image/pc0qot0ap/)

Comment: show some sample data and expected result

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have added the sample data

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery in the `WHERE`

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DebitSheet]
   ([Date]
   ,[RMMName]
   ,[Invoice]
   ,[PQNumber]
   ,[CAF]          
   ,[Percentage]
   ,[Amount]
   ,[FileName])
SELECT [Date]
   ,[RMMName]
   ,[Invoice]
   ,[PQNumber]
   ,[CAF]          
   ,[Percentage]
   ,[Amount]
FROM [dbo].[TempDebitSheet]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT tmp.[PQNumber] 
    FROM [dbo].[TempDebitSheet] tmp
    WHERE tmp.[PQNumber] = [TempDebitSheet].[PQNumber]
    GROUP BY tmp.[PQNumber]
    HAVING SUM(tmp.[Percentage]) = 100       
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query like this
Insert into ...
Select result.*, @filename from (....) result